# Can't 'cons' an Elm list

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I'm coming from an F# background and I'm trying to 'cons' an item on to a list like this...

In the repl directly...

```
model = {things = []}
morethings = model.things :: "anything"
```

but the compiler says this ..

```
 (::) is expecting the right side to be a:

    List (List String)

But the right side is:

    String
```

This is such a simple thing that i must be missing something fundamental. Why can't I cons a new string to that list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in Elm are not represented as a list of characters so they can't be used as the right side of a cons operation.

Are you instead trying to add `"anything"` onto the head of an empty list? If so, the order is this:

```elm
morethings = "anything" :: model.things
-- yields: ["anything"]
```